# Tensorboard 2.2.1 Windows 10- No Dashboard Active for the Current Dataset

Tags: deep-learning, windows-10, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I have run a Keras code and generated log files for tensorboard. Tensorboard extension is not loading in Jupyter Notebook. Hence i tried to launch Tensorboard from the Command Prompt. But i always get the message that **No dashboards are active for the current data set**.
Here are my files generated

[image]

I ran the command

[image: Command]

Error:

[image: Issue]

I tried couple of hacks from google but nothing worked.

**EDIT1:**

I installed ***protbuf*** using pip and was able to load tensorboard after i restarted my machine. However now i have another issue.

I defined Log Dir:

[image]

%load_ext tensorboard
[image]

This is creating the right log files and when i start the session in Jupyter it does not load the first time. If i run it again, it loads but says no dashboard available. If i restart my machine and launch tensorboard from Command Prompt again, this works for the same log directory

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code related to Tensorboard, and how did you define logdir.

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati- Hi added some code snippets.

Comment: It works intermittently but the behavior is very unpredictable